# R- Merge variable number of rows in multiple columns based on non-empty rows in other column

Tags: r

I extracted a table from a PDF file with extract_tables(), but the text has been spread out across multiple rows. The number of rows varies per record. I would like to combine the text into a single value.

What I would like to do is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008209/with-r-combine-text-from-variable-number-of-rows-into-single-text-element). The difference is that I have text in multiple columns. The number of records that each entry uses is variable, depending on a different column each time.

Example: One entry may take up four rows because the "Name & location" column is spread out across four rows, (while the other columns only take up two rows for that entry; the rest is filled with NA). For another entry, the text may be spread out across 6 rows, due to the length of the text in the "Expertise" column.

A new record starts every time when the "Level" column contains a value, rather than NA. **Edit:** the "Level" values are non-unique

My data looks like this:

```
Name & location                 Expertise           Type            Sector               Payment            Level
 1:   Ms. Jane                  Student             Higher          Government and       payment               1
 2:   Doe,                      <NA>                Education       education            has been           <NA>
 3:   NUS                       <NA>                institute       <NA>                 received           <NA>
 4:   Andrew Saunders Phd.,     Chief               Municipal       Government and       payment               5
 5:   Municipality of           Education           government      education            has not            <NA>
 6:   Amsterdam                 Officer             <NA>            <NA>                 been               <NA>
 7:   <NA>                      <NA>                <NA>            <NA>                 received           <NA>
 8:   Mr. Stephen               Spokesperson for    Municipal       Government and       payment               3
 9:   Johnson,                  Sustainability,     government      education            has not            <NA>
10:   Orange County             Health &            <NA>            <NA>                 been               <NA>
11:   <NA>                      Wellbeing and       <NA>            <NA>                 received           <NA>
12:   <NA>                      Wellfare            <NA>            <NA>                 <NA>               <NA>
13:   Mrs. Susan                Junior              national        Government and       payment               4
14:   Andrews,                  Research            government      education            has not            <NA>
15:   Police                    Manager             <NA>            <NA>                 been               <NA>
16:   <NA>                      Money               <NA>            <NA>                 received           <NA>
17:   <NA>                      Laundering          <NA>            <NA>                 <NA>               <NA>
```

Reproducible Example:

```
structure(list(`Name & location` = c("1:   Ms. Jane", "2:   Doe,", 
"3:   NUS", "4:   Andrew Saunders Phd.,", "5:   Municipality of", 
"6:   Amsterdam", "7:   <NA>", "8:   Mr. Stephen", "9:   Johnson,", 
"10:   Orange County", "11:   <NA>", "12:   <NA>", "13:   Mrs. Susan", 
"14:   Andrews,", "15:   Police", "16:   <NA>", "17:   <NA>"), 
    Expertise = c("Student", NA, NA, "Chief", "Education", "Officer", 
    NA, "Spokesperson for", "Sustainability,", "Health &", "Wellbeing and", 
    "Wellfare", "Junior", "Research", "Manager", "Money", "Laundering"
    ), Type = c("Higher", "Education", "Insititute", "Municipal", 
    "Government", NA, NA, "Municipal", "Government", NA, NA, 
    NA, "National", "Government", NA, NA, NA), Sector = c("Government and", 
    "education", NA, "Government and", "education", NA, NA, "Government and", 
    "education", NA, NA, NA, "Government and", "education", NA, 
    NA, NA), Payment = c("payment", "has been", "received", "Payment", 
    "has not", "been", "received", "Payment", "has not", "been", 
    "received", NA, "Payment", "has not", "been", "received", 
    NA), Level = c(1, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I tried so far is different versions of the code below

```
DF_clean <- DF %>% mutate(Level = ifelse(grepl(NA, Level))) %>%
  group_by(id = cumsum(!is.na(Level))) %>% 
  mutate(Level = first(Level)) %>% 
  group_by(Level) %>% 
  summarise(Name = paste(Name, collapse = " "),
            Expertise = paste(Expertise, collapse = " "),
            Type = paste(Type, collapse = " "),
            Sector = paste(Sector, collapse = " "),
            Level = paste(Level, collapse = " "))
```

But this seems to collapse all text into a single record.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are surely some prettier solutions, but this seems to work. It also works if `Level` contains duplicate values.

```
# Remove row numbers and <NA> from Name & Location
df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Name & location` = gsub("[0-9]+:\\s+", "", `Name & location`)) %>%
  mutate(`Name & location` = gsub("<NA>", "", `Name & location`))

# Compute ranges to merge
starts <- c(which(!is.na(df$Level)), nrow(df) + 1)
ranges <- sapply(
  1:(length(starts) - 1), 
  function(x) 
    starts[x]:(starts[x + 1] - 1)
)

# Merge lines based on ranges
combined_df <- lapply(
  ranges,
  function(x)
    lapply(df[x, ], function(x) gsub(" +$| NA", "", paste0(x, collapse = " ")))
) %>%
  bind_rows


# A tibble: 4 x 6
  `Name & location`                               Expertise                                                        Type                        Sector                   Payment                       Level
  <chr>                                           <chr>                                                            <chr>                       <chr>                    <chr>                         <chr>
1 Ms. Jane Doe, NUS                               Student                                                          Higher Education Insititute Government and education payment has been received     1    
2 Andrew Saunders Phd., Municipality of Amsterdam Chief Education Officer                                          Municipal Government        Government and education Payment has not been received 5    
3 Mr. Stephen Johnson, Orange County              Spokesperson for Sustainability, Health & Wellbeing and Wellfare Municipal Government        Government and education Payment has not been received 3    
4 Mrs. Susan Andrews, Police                      Junior Research Manager Money Laundering                         National Government         Government and education Payment has not been received 4
```

**EDIT:**
I used @Andrew's solution to compute a new `unique_level` column and make it work. It's prettier than my first solution IMHO:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Name & location` = gsub("[0-9]+:\\s+", "", `Name & location`)) %>%
  mutate(`Name & location` = gsub("<NA>", "", `Name & location`)) %>%
  mutate(unique_level = ifelse(!is.na(Level), 1, NA) * 1:nrow(df)) %>%
  fill(unique_level, .direction = "down") %>%
  group_by(unique_level) %>%
  summarise_all(~ gsub(" +$| NA", "", paste(., collapse = " "))) %>%
  select(-unique_level)
```

The first two `mutate` calls remove the row numbers and `<NA>` from the `Name & location` column. The `gsub` call in `summarise_all` removes trailing spaces and `NA` added when pasting rows together.

Comment: Your first solution works like a charm! Thank you very much!  The second one still groups based on the "Level" column. But I suppose you wanted to show the solution for unique levels?

Comment: @AmyvV: I didn't see the `Level` duplicates problem at first! I wrote a new solution based on @Andrew's answer to make it work, see my edit. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks! Check @Andrew solution as well, he took the time to correct it and it's now even better than mine!

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**:

Here, this cleans it up a bit and also works with non-unqiue levels. You'll also need `data.table` installed because I use `rleid` to create a new level variable (assuming it was ok to overwrite it and lose actual level values). If you need to retain you original levels just create a new rleid level column and group by that. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
df1 %>%
  fill(Level, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(`Name & location` = gsub("[0-9]+:\\s+(<NA>)*", "", `Name & location`)) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), "") %>%
  group_by(Level = data.table::rleid(Level)) %>%
  summarise_all(~trimws(paste(., collapse = " ") 

Level `Name & location`                  Expertise                                 Type              Sector           Payment            
  <chr> <chr>                              <chr>                                     <chr>             <chr>            <chr>              
1 1     Ms. Jane Doe, NUS                  Student                                   Higher Education~ Government and ~ payment has been r~
2 2     Andrew Saunders Phd., Municipalit~ Chief Education Officer                   Municipal Govern~ Government and ~ Payment has not be~
3 3     Mr. Stephen Johnson, Orange County Spokesperson for Sustainability, Health ~ Municipal Govern~ Government and ~ Payment has not be~
4 4     Mrs. Susan Andrews, Police         Junior Research Manager Money Laundering  National Governm~ Government and ~ Payment has not be~
```

Comment: This solution groups the data based on the Level column, right? For the reprex, it seems to work, but on my actual data, it doesn't. In the actual dataset, levels are not unique and may occur for more than one record. This might not have been clear in the question, sorry!

Comment: My solution isn't as pretty as @Andrew's, but it works with non unique levels.

Comment: Interesting. With this solution (and by retaining the original level column), 6 records disappear. The textual values of the records that disappeared seem to be included in the values of other records.

Comment: Hmm, very odd! Any way you can reproduce the issue?